# What are some of the not-so-common issues with getting remote access to a SQL 2k8 instance?

Tags: windows, sql-server-2008

Howdy... here on my local LAN, I have a Windows Server 2k8 box with SQL Server 2k8 installed.  I can connect to the database engine using the SSMS tool on the server, but attempting to connect to the database engine from a remote machine (also on the same LAN), the connection fails with the usual generic message about not being able to contact the server.

Before you offer the "usual" solutions, please let me say that I have already verified the instance name, verified that the instance is configured to allow remote connections, verified that the SQL Browser service is running, and verified that neither the Windows Firewall on the server nor on the client is getting in the way (tested with both completely disabled). I've even attempted to connect via the servers IP address on the LAN rather than it's Windows hostname.  :)

Does anyone know of any "uncommon" reasons (or even common ones that I failed to mention here) why I would be unable to connect to the database engine from a remote machine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server Configuration Manager in Network Configuration-> Protocols enable TCP/IP   or other protocols that you need. The default is: only Shared Memory.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you tried with the windows firewall disabled on both client and target, but is there also a virus scanner running on either/both machines? I've been caught out in the past where the virus checker has an integral firewall as well.

Failing that this [MS forum article](http://forums.microsoft.com/TechNet/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=2669287&SiteID=17) contains a list of things to check.

Answer (score 1):

I would check to see if you enabled remote connections on the specific IPv6 addresses, as if your are on the local network and connecting from Vista you may be connecting over IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.msdn.com/sql_protocols/archive/2006/09/30/SQL-Server-2005-Remote-Connectivity-Issue-TroubleShooting.aspx